# MATLAB non-linear optimization data set

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a non-linear optimization program using [fmincon](http://www.mathworks.se/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fmincon.html). I want MATLAB to read through a data set and compare those values to the constraints. (It is the size of an electrical generator based on electric and heat demand over a one month period).

How do I start this off?

Comment: not sure I get this: do you have a function call (with variables) or not? If so, look at the fmincon documentation. If you need more help, I need more info. If not, fmincon is not your solution, rather you probably want something like `lsqnonlin`

Comment: hey Rasman. yes i do have a funciton call with two unknown variables in. Fmincon is the solver i need (constrained, non linear) but because matlab is reading off a spreadsheet, then the equation depends on what the integer value in each cell is.